# What script can I use to make a copy of a sheet each day automatically?

Tags: automation, google-sheets

I have google sheet template made for a local business. The template will be used in a store day to day. I need a Script that duplicates the sheet each day automatically so we don't manually have to. I want the sheets to stay in the same spread sheet, but each tab is a new day. The tab i want to be the date of the day. I know i can use a trigger to auto generate but I don't know how to copy the exact template or change the name of the tab autmatically

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
function duplicateSpreadSheets() {
    var sheetName, sheet, destination, currentDate;

    sheetName = "Name of sheet goes here";

    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName(sheetName);
    destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID goes here (the first string of nubmers and letters in the url)");

    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("Copy of " + sheetName)
        .activate();

    currentDate = new Date(Date.now()); //change the format of the date to what you want, DD/MM/YYYY etc.

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .renameActiveSheet(currentDate)
}
```

Go to Resources > All your triggers.. and make this function trigger once per day.

Also keep in mind that Google Spreadsheets has a hard limit of 200 sheets per workbook (or used to, not sure if this has changed) so after 200 days this will stop working.

Comment: it said that it had bad value line 8

Comment: i got it line 8 to work but now on line 10 its giving me and activiate null error